# Running execute_script with variable inside in Python via Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to execute a little Python script which runs a function via selenium in a firefox browser.

Now I use:

```
pageurl = 'https://www.google.com'
driver.get(pageurl)
driver.execute_script("alert('hi')")
```

Which indeed runs the alert box on in firefox, and shows 'hi'.

I want to be able to let alert output/run a variable.

So like this:

```
pageurl = 'https://www.google.com'
driver.get(pageurl)
keyy = 'blabla'
driver.execute_script("alert(keyy)")
```

But instead of running the alert command, I get an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeroen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("alert(keyy)")
  File "C:\Users\Jeroen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Jeroen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Jeroen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: keyy is not defined
```

How should I be writing `driver.execute_script("alert(keyy)")` ?

Comment: `driver.execute_script("alert('%s')" % keyy)`

Comment: @thebjorn how to do it if I need to perform any numerical operation with a JavaScript variable inside `driver.execute_script("<HERE>")`?

Comment: @hafiz031 that is an entirely new question (please ask a new question - asking new questions in comments of 18+ month old questions is not likely to get any exposure).

Comment: @thebjorn here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65274678/6907424

Answer (score 1):

you can use string formatting to put the value inside your string:

```
script = "alert('{}')".format(keyy)
driver.execute_script(script)
```